# Dynamically adding data attribute to element

Tags: javascript, dataset

How to add data-name dynamically to an element but not dataset what add data=" ", but only data?
Something like this:

```
<div class="battle-screen__bullet" data-bullet></div>
```

Comment: You don't say how data coming.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div.battle-screen__bullet')
el.dataset.bullet_new = ''
```

dom will become

```html
<div class="battle-screen__bullet" data-bullet data-bullet_new></div>
```

Comment: but there is still with " "

Comment: @wnq What does <but there is still with " "> mean ?

Comment: data-bullet="", but i want to add just clear data-bullet for example without " = ' ' "

Comment: sorry, Still don't understand what you mean

Comment: I just want this: <div class="battle-screen__bullet" data-bullet></div>  , not this: <div class="battle-screen__bullet" data-bullet = " "></div>

Comment: <div class="battle-screen__bullet" data-bullet></div> is equivalent to <div class="battle-screen__bullet" data-bullet = " "></div>